# How to get index of removed data on taginput

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery.tagsinput.js for taginput.
I want to get index of removed data. I could not do it .My code below ,how can I solve it?

Thank you

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Input Tags</label>
    <div class="col-md-12col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input id="tags_1" type="text" name="category_properties" class="tags form-control"
            value="<?php echo $getcategory['category_properties'];?>" on-tag-removed="" ; />
        <div id="suggestions-container" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 250px; margin: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tags_1").tagsInput({
    width: "auto",
    onRemoveTag: () => {},
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by index?

Comment: can also be value of removed data

Comment: Why would you need the index?  It doesn't make any sense if it's already been removed

Comment: I need index because I keep data on the table with same value and same index , I will delete that data too when I remove on input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can also be value of removed data

The removed data is provided in the `onRemove` callback.

```
onRemoveTag: function(val) { },
```

Example snippet:

```js
$('#tag1').tagsInput({
    onRemoveTag: function(val) {
      console.log("remove", val)
      console.log(this)
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper { 
 margin: 20px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css">

<div id="wrapper">
<p>This is a basic tag input: 
    <input id="tag1" value="alpha,beta,gamma" />
</p>
</div>
```

The index doesn't appear to have a meaning, you would need to know the value of all the tags before removal and compare after removal.  If you're using the index to get the value, it would be too late as the value has already been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching through results, and getting index of found one

```
 $('#tags_1').tagsInput({
    width: 'auto',
    onChange: function(elem, elem_tags)
    {
      $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function()
      {
        if($(this).value==elem.get(0).value)
          alert($(this).index() );
      });
    }
  });
```

And value of removed data is just

```
$('#tags_1').tagsInput({
    width: 'auto',
    onChange: function(elem, elem_tags)
    {
      alert( "I removed this: " + elem.get(0).value);
          
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain how onchange works instead of onRemoveTag that OP is using?

Comment: `elem.get is not a function`

Comment: Tested, onChange is *not* called when removing a tag